# Are there any stories or descriptions in Hindu writings about the Universe and the Earth before humanity was born?

Tags: history, earth, universe

I was searching for stories before humanity in Hindu texts. But found none. Can you tell me if any exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Vishnu Purana narrates on this topic. Parasara sage tells:

> Maitreya, listen attentively, how this deity, the lord of all, created
>   the gods and other beings.
>
> Whilst he (Brahmá) formerly, in the beginning of the Kalpas, was.
>   meditating on creation, there appeared a creation beginning with
>   ignorance, and consisting of darkness. From that great being appeared
>   five fold Ignorance, consisting of obscurity, illusion, extreme
>   illusion, gloom, utter darkness. The creation of the creator thus
>   plunged in abstraction, was the five fold (immovable) world, without
>   intellect or reflection, void of perception or sensation, incapable of
>   feeling, and destitute of motion. Since immovable things were first
>   created, this is called the first creation. Brahmá, beholding that it
>   was defective, designed another; and whilst he thus meditated, the
>   animal creation was manifested, to the products of which the term
>   Tiryaksrotas is applied, from their nutriment following a winding
>   course. These were called beasts, &c., and their characteristic was
>   the quality of darkness, they being destitute of knowledge,
>   uncontrolled in their conduct, and mistaking error for wisdom; being
>   formed of egotism and self-esteem, labouring under the twenty-eight
>   kinds of imperfection, manifesting inward sensations, and associating
>   with each other (according to their kinds).
>
> Beholding this creation also imperfect, Brahmá again meditated, and a
>   third creation appeared, abounding with the quality of goodness,
>   termed Úrddhasrotas.  The beings thus produced in the Úrddhasrotas
>   creation were endowed with pleasure and enjoyment, unencumbered
>   internally or externally, and luminous within and without. This,
>   termed the creation of immortals, was the third performance of Brahmá,
>   who, although well pleased with it, still found it incompetent to
>   fulfil his end. Continuing therefore his meditations, there sprang, in
>   consequence of his infallible purpose, the creation termed
>   Arváksrotas, from indiscreet nature. The products of this are termed
>   Arváksrotasas, from the downward current (of their nutriment). They
>   abound with the light of knowledge, but the qualities of darkness and
>   of foulness predominate. Hence they are afflicted by evil, and are
>   repeatedly impelled to action. They have knowledge both externally and
>   internally, and are the instruments (of accomplishing the object of
>   creation, the liberation of soul). These creatures were mankind.
>
> I have thus explained to you, excellent Muni, six creations. The first
>   creation was that of Mahat or Intellect, which is also called the
>   creation of Brahmá. The second was that of the rudimentary principles
>   (Tanmátras), thence termed the elemental creation (Bhúta serga). The
>   third was the modified form of egotism, termed the organic creation,
>   or creation of the senses (Aindríyaka). These three were the Prákrita
>   creations, the developments of indiscrete nature, preceded by the
>   indiscreet principle. The fourth or fundamental creation (of
>   perceptible things) was that of inanimate bodies. The fifth, the
>   Tairyag yonya creation, was that of animals. The sixth was the
>   Úrddhasrotas creation, or that of the divinities.

The creation of the

> Arváksrotas beings was the seventh, and was that of man. There is an
>   eighth creation, termed Anugraha, which possesses both the qualities
>   of goodness and darkness. Of these creations, five are secondary, and
>   three are primary. But there is a ninth,the Kaumára creation, which is
>   both primary and secondary. These are the nine creations of the great
>   progenitor of all, and, both as primary and secondary, are the radical
>   causes of the world, proceeding from the sovereign creator. What else
>   dost thou desire to hear?

Source: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp039.htm