# Hierarchy of entities spanning from gross body or senses to parabrahman

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, brahman, indriyas

Across the scriptures, different hierarchies has been mentioned regarding entities related human life. For example consider the following hierarchies:

**#1**: Hierarchy by Krishna

> The senses are superior to the gross body, and superior to the senses
> is the mind. Beyond the mind is the intellect, and even beyond the
> intellect is the soul.
>
> [[Verse 42, Chapter 3, Bhagavad Gita,The Mahabharata]](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3/verse/42)

**#2**: Hierarchy by Vyasa

> The objects of the senses are superior to the senses themselves. The
> mind is superior to those objects. The understanding is superior to
> the mind. The Soul, also called Mahat, is superior to the
> understanding. Superior to Mahat is the Unmanifest (or Prakriti).
> Superior to the Unmanifest is Brahma. There is nothing Superior to
> Brahma. That is the highest limit of excellence and the highest goal.
>
> [[Section 246, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b073.htm)

To be concise, the two hierarchies are as follows:

> Gross body (sthula shareer) -> Senses (indriya) -> Mind (manas) ->
> Intellect (buddhi) -> soul (athman?)
>
> Senses (indriyas) -> Objects of senses (indriyarthas) -> Mind (manas) -> Understanding (buddhi?) -> Mahat soul (athman?) ->
> Unmanifest prakriti (avyaktha) -> Parabrahman

I kept question mark wherever I am not confident enough about the translation. But this question is not about that.

Krishna's hierarchy is abstracted comparatively (with Vyasa). There are five entities in Krishna's hierarchy and seven in Vyasa's. krishna's hierarchy has gross body, which is not in Vyasa's hierarchy. Vyasa enumerated some more entities in hierarchy.

Please provide me more such hierarchies, which has to be different from the above two, that may span from gross body to parabrahman. The hierarchies has to be either abstract or specific than the above two mentioned or may introduce some new entities at any level of hierarchy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Earth and pancha bootha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31977/earth-and-pancha-bootha) & [Are there any stories or descriptions in Hindu writings about the Universe and the Earth before humanity was born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/are-there-any-stories-or-descriptions-in-hindu-writings-about-the-universe-and-t/7445#7445)

Comment: The hierarchies are the same. The constituent elements are the same, they have been summarized or compartmentalized differently; but they are the same.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda True...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda But I am asking for similar hierarchies in scriptures. Please read. Different in the sense of more abstract or more specific only.